# Passing value back from a called activity

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and have the following question.

I have an Activity (screen) which calls another activity (screen).  I can pass values back from Activity2 by creating an intext and using putExtras.  Then when I return to my main activity1 then I can (onActivityResult) I can retrive the string value pairs from the intent that is returned.

Question 1 if Activity2 is finished what is the possibility that the Intent i created in there can get freed up if the garbage collector kicks in?  Or does android not clear up any memory like that until the app is exited.

Question 2 ) If I then go back into Activity2 and again do a "new Intent ....." is that allocating even more memory and if so is it inefficient?"

Question 3 - Is there a better way of passing data back from a called activity to the calling activity or is using an Intent and putExtras etc the only way?

Thanks 
Tony

Answer (score 2):

In class from which you want to send data-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,NextClass.class); 
intent.putExtra("ACTIVITY_ID","Any value or variable" );
intent.putExtra("CUSTOMER_ID","Any Value or variable" );
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Now in Receiving class, lets say NextClass

```
Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
String ACTIVITY_ID=extras.getString("ACTIVITY_ID");
String CUSTOMER_ID=extras.getString("CUSTOMER_ID");
```

By using this method we can easily pass data from one activity to another...

Comment: This is something like what I am doing, but I am passing back from a called activity.

Comment: as mentioned in above post you can make global static variables and set required value for that variable and whenever you required you can access...

Answer (score 1):

My Suggestion Would be.

If you have data which has been used various activity then Instead passing the data by using the Intent from 1 activity to another. create Global Level Static variable and then access that that Global variable through out the application.

Comment: If you got the idea from the above answer then Can you please accept the answer so that it can be help full to others.

Comment: I thought global variables were a "bad" thing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How much data are you going to pass between activities? Bytes, Kilobytes or Megabytes?

If its only bytes or some kilobytes then this is my answer:

1. don't worry about the garbage collector.It will do its job
2. yes more memory will be allocated. no it is not inefficient
3. Intent and putExtras is the preferred way.

If the data is really large and you can save it to sd card and pass a file uri between activities.